# I dont understand my error

Tags: errors, code, compilation-error

The error that comes up is that I must insert a $ but I dont know where to insert the $.
Below is what I wrote in Overleaf.

````
\subsection{BCA Protein Assay}

\textbf{Calibration curve}

To create a calibration curve to measure the sample against, a series of two-fold dilutions are needed by combining BSA (100mg/ml) and Ripa Buffer (see Table 1). In which the previous solution is used to create the next solution, to calculate the amount of BSA and Ripa Buffer needed in each dilution, the following formula is used. Initial concentration x Initial Volume = Final Concentration x Final Volume: $C_i$ x $V_i$ = $C_2$ x $V_2$.

(1) 100mg/ml = $C_i$ , 2mg/ml = $C_2$ , 200$\mu l$ = $V_2$ \\
    100mg/ml x $V_i$ = 2mg/ml x 200$\mu l$ \implies $V_i$ = 4$\mu l$ \\
    In dilution 1, 4 $\mu l$ of BSA is needed and therefore 196$\mu l$ of Ripa buffer to create a 200 $\mu l$ solution.

(2) 2mg/ml = $C_i$ , 1mg/ml = $C_2$ , 200$\mu l$ = $V_2$
    2mg/ml x $V_i$ = 1mg/ml x 200$\mu l$ \implies $V_i$ = 100$\mu l$ 
    In Dilution 2, 100$\mu l$ of BSA is needed and therefore 100$\mu l$ of Ripa buffer to create a 200$\mu l$ solution. 
The calculation was repeated for all of the dilutions below.

\textbf{Preparation of Sample and Cell Media }

The Sample is diluted with Ripa Buffer to create different concentrations. The following formula is used to calculate how much Ripa Buffer and Sample/Cell Media are required for each dilution: 

(1) 100mg/ml = $C_i$, 10mg/ml = $C_2$ , 300$\mu l$ = $V_2$ \\
    100mg/ml x $V_i$ = 10mg/ml x 300$\mu l$ \implies $V_i$ = 30$\mu l$ \\
    In Dilution 1, 30$\mu l$ of Sample/Cell Media is needed and therefore 270$\mu l$ of Ripa buffer to create a 300$\mu l$ solution. 
The calculation was repeated for all dilutions below.

\textbf{Preparation of BCA Reagent }

To prepare the Bicinchoninic Acid BCAa and BCAb are combined at 50:1 in a total 20ml solution.
19.6ml of BCAa and 0.4ml of BCAb


\subsection{Assessment of plasma apoE monomers, homodimers and heterodimers}

A\% = \frac{$OD_A$}{$OD_A$ + $OD_B$ + $OD_C$}


\subsection{Determination of total plasma apoE concentrations}
\textbf{Calibration Curve} \\
To create a calibration curve to measure the ApoE concentration of the samples, a series of two-fold dilutions are needed by combining ApoE(16000pg/ml) and Blocking Buffer (see Table 1). In which the previous solution is used to create the next solution,the following formula is used: $C_i$ x $V_i$ = $C_2$ x $V_2$.

(1) 16000pg/ml = $C_i$ , 8000pg/ml = $C_2$ , 1ml = $V_2$ \\
    16000 pg/ml x $V_i$ = 8000pg/ml x 1ml \implies $V_i$ = 0.5ml```
````

Comment: Overleaf handles errors very badly, and the source of the problem could be before the part you showed. Please provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) so that people can actually run tests.

Comment: There are a number of math mode errors in the code posted. `\implies` needs to be in math mode; so does `\frac` (and the contents *inside* the frac are already in math mode, so you shouldn't use `$`s on the inside). There are also misuses of "x" for multiplication; you should use `\times` and that should be inside math mode too.

Comment: I would recommend learning how to use the `siunitx` package so you don't have to break out of math mode so often. For example line 14 could then read `$\si{100\mg\per\ml} \times V_i = \si{2\mg\per\ml} \times 200\si{\ul} \implies V_i = \si{\ul}$`, with just one math block.

Comment: Does math mode refer to letter or number in side of $$.

Comment: Math mode refers to *everything* between the `$` signs.

Answer (score 3):

Considered @frabjous  comment, your code fragment can be rewritten in the following form:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\section{unknown}
\subsection{BCA Protein Assay}

\textbf{Calibration curve}

To create a calibration curve to measure the sample against, a series of two-fold dilutions are needed by combining BSA (\qty{100}{mg/ml}) and Ripa Buffer (see Table 1). In which the previous solution is used to create the next solution, to calculate the amount of BSA and Ripa Buffer needed in each dilution, the following formula is used. $\text{Initial concentration} \times \text{Initial Volume} = \text{Final Concentration} \times \text{Final Volume}$: $C_i \times V_i = C_2 \times V_2$.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
\item   $\qty{100}{mg/ml} = C_i$, $\qty{2}{mg/ml} = C_2$, $\qty{200}{\micro\liter} = V_2$  

        $\qty{100}{mg/ml}   \times V_i = \qty{2}{mg/ml} \times \qty{200}{\micro\litre} \implies V_i = \qty{4}{\micro\liter}$

        In dilution 1, \qty{4}{\micro\liter} of BSA is needed and therefore \qty{196}{\micro\liter} of Ripa buffer to create a \qty{200}{\micro\liter} solution.
\item   $\qty{2}{mg/ml} = C_i$, $\qty{1}{mg/ml} = C_2$, $\qty{200}{\micro\liter} = V_2$
        $\qty{2}{mg/ml} \times V_i = \qty{1}{mg/ml} \times \qty{200}{\micro\liter} \implies V_i = \qty{100}{\micro\liter}$.

        In Dilution 2, \qty{100}{\micro\liter} of BSA is needed and therefore \qty{100}{\micro\liter} of Ripa buffer to create a \qty{200}{\micro\liter} solution.
    \end{enumerate}
The calculation was repeated for all of the dilutions below.
    
\textbf{Preparation of Sample and Cell Media }

The Sample is diluted with Ripa Buffer to create different concentrations. The following formula is used to calculate how much Ripa Buffer and Sample/Cell Media are required for each dilution:
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
\item   $\qty{100}{mg/ml} = C_i$, $\qty{10}{mg/ml} = C_2$, $\qty{300}{\micro\liter} = V_2$ \\

    $\qty{100}{mg/ml} \times V_i = \qty{10}{mg/ml} \times \qty{300}{\micro\liter} \implies V_i = \qty{30}{\micro\liter}$.
    
    In Dilution 1, \qty{30}{\micro\liter} of Sample/Cell Media is needed and therefore 270$\mu l$ of Ripa buffer to create a \qty{300}{\micro\liter} solution.
    \end{enumerate}
The calculation was repeated for all dilutions below.

\textbf{Preparation of BCA Reagent}

To prepare the Bicinchoninic Acid BCAa and BCAb are combined at 50:1 in a total 20ml solution.
19.6ml of BCAa and 0.4ml of BCAb


\subsection{Assessment of plasma apoE monomers, homodimers and heterodimers}
\[
A\,\% = \frac{OD_A}{OD_A + OD_B + OD_C}
\]

\subsection{Determination of total plasma apoE concentrations}
\textbf{Calibration Curve} 

To create a calibration curve to measure the ApoE concentration of the samples, a series of two-fold dilutions are needed by combining ApoE (\qty{16000}{pg/ml}) and Blocking Buffer (see Table 1). In which the previous solution is used to create the next solution,the following formula is used: $C_i \times V_i = C_2 \times V_2$.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
\item   $\qty{16000}{pg/ml} = C_i$, $\qty{8000}{pg/ml} = C_2$, $\qty{1}{ml} = V_2$ 
    
        $\qty{16000}{pg/ml} \times V_i = \qty{8000}{pg/ml} \times \qty{1}{ml} \implies V_i = \qty{0.5}{ml}$
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]